# Which underground opposition parties exist in China?

Tags: china, opposition

In [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_parties_in_China) I read about a couple of banned parties operating in China in the underground.

Are there any more underground parties that don't get coverage in China?

Comment: I also read the Wikipedia article and could not find information about parties that are banned and operating in the underground. The page rather lists parties that have been banned and there is still the possibility that they simply ceased to exist. Could you help me find the information about the banned parties still operating?

Comment: Also I think it's safe to say that as soon as the public knows about such a party still operating the Chinese government will try to hunt them down. Therefore little reliable information should exist and the answers might be too speculative or rather vague making it maybe not an ideal fit here. It may be one of these topics where you maybe cannot know the truth.

Comment: Opposition parties all around China?

Comment: The notion of "underground" is kind of a challenge. If they are really such, then there would be no official knowledge of them. For example, I have no faintest clue what underground political movements might exist in my own country.

Comment: @BobaFit Agree, the question is a bit self-negating. If someone answers with a credible organization, then it won't be underground any more.

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo Underground means they are illegal it doesn't mean they have a complete secrecy. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_parties_in_the_Soviet_Union

During Apartheid the ANC was underground but people still knowed that it existed.

Comment: @Apoliticalboy The ANC was a big, well-known political faction even in the 70s and 80s, it had officers, records, a PR spokesman, received foreign officials, had organized paperwork, etc... It was not 'underground' in any way.

Comment: Was litterally called underground. 
https://www.jstor.org/stable/40864727

"In particular, it formed the basis for establishing the ANC
underground immediately after its banning."
https://www.sahistory.org.za/sites/default/files/anc_underground_mplan_rivonia.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but they cannot organise in a way that presents any kind of threat to the CCP without being shut down.

In a democratic country, a political party will have a membership, it will raise money, it will therefore have a constitution, a bank account, a group of trustees and so on.  None of these are possible in China.

Instead, Amnesty International talks about ["civil society organizations."](https://www.amnesty.org/en/location/asia-and-the-pacific/east-asia/china/report-china/#:%7E:text=10%20years%E2%80%99%20imprisonment.-,Freedom%20of%20association,-Authorities%20continued%20to) These will be small and informal.  It is out of the question that they could openly campaign.  They certainly couldn't have a bank account.  They might be a social media group, or an informal association that follows a blog.

There may be groups which are outwardly non-political, but in which the members have a common interest in politics.

Such groups may still be subject to the National Security Law and Societies Ordinance. If the police suspect that a video games group is starting to talk politics at its meetings, they can and will shut them down, and possibly incarnate the leaders.

Amnesty don't name or identify such groups - as to do so would cause them to be targeted, so I shan't either.

Comment: I'm just going to leave that typo, because it is funny.

Comment: So the Western countries are all so democratic?Not only CIA is invading your personal life by spying on you constantly if you say that you dont like e.g Biden you may be fired from your current job?Or if you have a different opinion you get expelled from school?https://thehill.com/changing-america/respect/equality/592311-student-sues-after-suspension-for-voicing-christian-beliefs/ and https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/lgbtq-students-texas-school-rainbow-stickers-rcna23208 and many more

Comment: When you say "In a democratic country,..."you should also include references to all "democratic countries"

Comment: @Volpina You might need to clarify your comments. The two stories linked have nothing to do with the CIA. The first story is regarding an administration overstepping 1st amendment rights of a student by allegedly violating religious beliefs. The 2nd story is more akin to the lady that refused to give out marriage certificates to gay couples based on her personal religious beliefs. Employees of the school were providing a political/religious service outside of the administrations guidelines. What they did would be no different than to put a Christian cross, Star of David, or Swastikas' on doors

Comment: You answer "Yes", but state *they cannot organise in a way that presents any kind of threat to the CCP without being shut down. ...  None of these are possible in China. ... "civil society organizations." ... small and informal*. So shouldn't your answer to the Q be "No"?